# How to get UISearchDisplayController to search only after search button is pressed

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am implementing search in my iOS app and so far I am using the shouldReloadTableForSearchString method to get the string from the search bar to execute the search. However I have noticed that the method calls whenever the string a user is entering changes. That's good to search through one's contacts but thats not what I'm using it for so I'm looking for a way to only start searching when the user has clicked search and entered their string not while their typing. How can I get that done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup a delegate for the search bar and implement the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` method. Do your searching from that method. Just return `NO` from the `shouldReloadTableForSearchString` method.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the delegate method in `UISearchDisplayDelegate` `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:`

you should be able to return false to stop the search.

something like

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    return false;
}
```

and then attach the Search button press event to do the actual reload by grabbing the search text, perform your search, then reload the table based on search.

if this is not your solution, then take a look at that [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate) class for the correct event to take action on.

Comment: `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString` will certainly keep the search from commencing if `false` is returned, but this would require unnecessary logic to determine "when" to search; and it doesn't quite give Michael Nana what he's looking for. Its better to use the delegate method `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`.

Answer (score 0):

implement `searchController.searchBar.delegate` & `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; 
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      //enter your search code
}
```